# Hazard rate question (Exercise 4.4.7 from Grimmett and Stirzaker)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Exercise 4.4.7 asks for the hazard rate of $X$ where $X$ has the Weibull distribution:
$$
P(X > x) = e^{-\alpha x^{\beta - 1}}{\rm \hspace{1cm} where\ } x \geq 0.
$$
I computed the answer to be $\alpha (\beta - 1) x^{\beta - 2}$ while the solutions manual says that the answer is $\alpha \beta x^{\beta - 1}$. Have I made a mistake or is the solutions manual incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ has probability density $f$, then the hazard rate function of $X$ is $h = \frac f{1-F}$ where $F$ is the distribution function of $X$. So we may compute for $t>0$
$$
h(t) = \frac{\alpha  (\beta -1) x^{\beta -2} e^{-\alpha  x^{\beta -1}}}{e^{-\alpha  x^{\beta -1}}} = \alpha(\beta-1)x^{\beta-2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for confirming the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your choice of parametrization.  The way you have characterized the survival function $$S_X(x) = \Pr[X > x] = \exp(-\alpha x^{\beta - 1}), \quad x \ge 0,$$ is a little different than other parametrizations.  Without seeing the source document to determine how the authors themselves chose to parametrize the distribution, it is premature to say where the discrepancy lies.

For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) parametrizes the survival as $$S_X(x) = \exp(-(x/\lambda)^k), \quad x \ge 0,$$ with the additional constraints on the parameters $k > 0$, $\lambda > 0$.  This of course is equivalent to your parametrization with the mapping $$\alpha = \lambda^{-k}, \quad \beta = 1 + k,$$ which would suggest that your parameters must be constrained to $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta > -1$.  The hazard rate in terms of the $k$-$\lambda$ parametrization would be $$h(x) = \frac{k x^{k-1}}{\lambda^k}.$$  Note that if the textbook authors had defined $$S_X(x) = \exp(-\alpha x^\beta), \quad x \ge 0,$$ which is a legitimate parametrization, they would conclude $h(x)$ to be of the form they say they got.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, the textbook defined the Weibull distribution of $X$ as $P(X > x) = e^{-\alpha x^{\beta - 1}}$ for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: @Raj In that case, the textbook is inconsistent with itself, as you surely have concluded by now.  Perhaps the authors did not recall how they parametrized the distribution when they wrote the answer.